# bind jquery click event to ids from settings

Tags: jquery

Im trying to create a jquery bind for settings I have in a namespace file

my namespace settings are something like this:

```
abc.settings = {
   saveBtnId : "#saveitem",
   cancelBtnId : "#cancelItem"
};
```

etc

And I am trying this:

```
   $(abc.settings.saveBtnId , abc.settings.cancelBtnId).bind("click", function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             var type = $(this).attr("data-id");
             alert(type);
   });
```

the problem is, I get no error ( as expected ) but I get no bindings either
I am using the latest jquery from CDN.

now you will have to forgive me if I am being a little lame here, but it is very late now
and energy in the brain is running low, but as always your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(abc.settings.saveBtnId + "," + abc.settings.cancelBtnId).bind(...
```

What you want is a selector that evaluates to be `"#saveitem,#cancelItem"`, so you need to concatenate your variables together with a comma.

What you are currently doing is passing two separate parameters to `$()` which kind of looks like it is the `$(selector, context)` syntax except that `context` is supposed to be a DOM Element, Document, or jQuery object, not a second string. For more info on what the parameters to `$()` do have a look at [the doco](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/).

Comment: works on second but not the first ! i know that usually it would look like this $("#firstid, #secondid").  the string above seems to ignore the first id though and just action the secondID

Comment: nope forgive me, your right! i was using the wrong setting name for the first button, :-) thanks very much ....

Comment: You're welcome. (And sorry, what I said initially about the second parameter wasn't right, but I've edited my answer to fix it.)

Comment: yeah that's fine, I totally understand good explanation though :-)

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$.each(['saveBtnId', 'cancelBtnId'], function(v, i) {
    $(abc.settings[v]).on('click', function() {
       ...
    });
});
```

It uses an array of strings (which could have been pre-assigned to another variable) and finds the appropriate property from your namespace and binds the click handler.

Alternatively, to preserve your namespaced properties:

```
$.each([abc.settings.saveBtnId, abc.settings.cancelBtnId], function() {
    $(this).on('click', function() {
       ...
    });
});
```

Comment: that does not because it does not use the namespace settings, used in order to prevent mistake across developers when it comes to IDs on objects and also to enable intellisense on the object when coding against too.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "not use the namespace settings" - they're in the second line.  There's no way to have your intellisense recognise the labels unless they're prefixed with the name space.  A string literal is the only way to use a variable to access the properties of an object.

Comment: i just think that adding ['saveBtnId', 'cancelBtnId']  is adding more scope and more things to correct, what if cancel button no longer was a cancel, and the client said, could this instead be a save and the save button be an order ?? you would have to go through your code!!   but maybe its ebcause i have never seen it wrote like that so dont quite understand what you have actually done and how its works!

Comment: @davethecoder changing the strings is no different to changing a property label, except that in the latter case you _might_ get help from your IDE's "refactor" tool.  The point of the `['a', 'b']` is to make it _easier_ to change the list of affected elements by not needing a large concatenation (per nnnnnn's answer).

Comment: yeah I understand re-factoring, and so do you.... but a hell of a lot of programmers don't even know that, anyway I have read over it a few times and yeah I understand, I also noticed your usage off on,  I like the idea of this, but hit and miss with IE especially on a windows phone, its a better option mind.   anyway thanks for your input, much appreciated

Comment: @davethecoder `.on()` is just the jQuery 1.7+ "catchall" way of registering events.  It works on any supported platform.

Comment: @davethecoder I've added a new code block which I think more closely achieves what you require, and without needing to use string concatenation.  (I _always_ try to avoid concatenation whenever possible when constructing selectors and HTML snippets because it's error prone and potentially bad for security).

Comment: arghhhh, see thats how I had it in the first place, kind of   hmmmmm  okay thanks, security YES I think I actually like this one better.

Comment: yeah doesent like that, changed code to match above ( without the .... ) :-) and nice but again cancels out for some reason